Validity of expectation handling in "decoupling" Lemma proof
I am taking a course in Random Matrix Theory, and recently the lecturer has introduced us the following lemma, which is considered auxiliary before we move to concentration inequalities. Now, since the lecture notes are handwritten, I had some trouble completely understanding the proof, written by the lecturer. Unfortunately, the lecturer doesn't reply to my emails, so I decided to try my luck here. I will now write down both the lemma and the proof.
Lemma: "Decoupling a dependent sequence".

Let $\xi=(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_M)$ be a sequence of independent RVs, s.t.
$\forall i: \mathbb{E}\xi_i=0$. Let $A_{jk}:\,j,k=1,\dots M$ be a
doubly-indexed sequence of elements (a matrix) in a vector space $X$.
Also let $F:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Then: $$
 \mathbb{E}\left[F\left(\sum_{j\neq
 k=1}^M\xi_j\xi_kA_{jk}\right)\right] \leq
 \mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j,k=1}^M\xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}\right)\right],
 $$ where $\xi'_k$ is an "independent copy" of $\xi_k$ for any $k$.
"Independent copy" means that the $k^{\text{th}}$ entrance of a
different seqence: $\xi'=(\xi'_1,\dots,\xi'_M)$ is drawn identically
from the same distribution as $\xi_k$.
Notice how on the LHS of the inequality summation is done only through disjoint indices (i.e. diagonal elements of $A$ are not included in summation), while on the RHS we sum over all indices.

Proof (as from the lecture notes):

Step 1: Introduce a sequence of RVs: $\delta = (\delta)_{i=1}^M$, s.t. $\forall i: \delta_i\overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}\mathrm{Bernoulli}(0.5)$. Notice that $\forall j\neq k$:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\delta_j(1-\delta_k)]=\frac{1}{4}.
$$
This yields:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}^*:&=\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(\sum_{j\neq k=1}^M\xi_j\xi_kA_{jk}\right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j\neq k=1}^M \underbrace{\mathbb{E}_\delta[\delta_j(1-\delta_k)]}_{\text{always }1/4}\xi_j\xi_kA_{jk}\right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(\mathbb{E}_\delta\left[4\sum_{j\neq k=1}^M\delta_j(1-\delta_k)\xi_j\xi_kA_{jk}\right]\right)\right]\\
&\overset{\text{Jensen}}{\leq} \mathbb{E}_\delta\left[\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j\neq k}^M\delta_j\xi_j(1-\delta_k)\xi_kA_{jk}\right)\right]\Bigg|\,\xi\right]
\end{align*}
$$
Step 2: Now, let $\sigma(\delta)=\{j\in\{1,\dots,M\}:\delta_j=1\}$. Let's call $\sigma$ the "left-hand side" set of indices.
Then recall that by Fubini's theorem, we can write a double integral over a product of domains as an iterated integral over each individual factor-domain. Then:
$$
\mathbb{E}_\delta\left[\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j\neq k}^M\delta_j\xi_j(1-\delta_k)\xi_kA_{jk}\right)\right]\Bigg| \,\xi\right] = \mathbb{E}_\delta\left[\mathbb{E}_\xi\left[F\left(4\sum_{j\in \sigma(\delta)}\sum_{k\not\in\sigma(\delta)}\xi_j\xi_kA_{jk}\right)\Bigg| \,\delta\right]\Bigg|\, \xi\right]
$$
Let's now analyze the inner expectation. Note that in it, an RV $\xi_i$ appears (conditioned on $\delta$):

either only as the $1^\text{st}$ factor (if $i\in\sigma(\delta)$)
or only as the $2^\text{nd}$ factor (otherwise)

So we can replace all $\xi_k: k\not\in\sigma(\delta)$ by i.i.d. $\xi'_k$ WLOG, change is only in terms of "relabelling", the expectation of each $\xi'_k$ is still $0$. We then write:
$$
\mathbb{E}^*\leq \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}_\delta\left[\mathbb{E}_\xi\left[F\left(4\sum_{j\in \sigma(\delta)}\sum_{k\not\in\sigma(\delta)}\xi_j\xi_kA_{jk}\right)\Bigg|\, \delta\right]\Bigg|\, \xi\right]\right]
$$
Step 3: Then we can assume that $\exists \delta_0$ and $\sigma_0=\sigma(\delta_0)$, s.t.:
$$
\mathbb{E}^* \leq \mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j\in\sigma_0}\sum_{k\not\in\sigma_0} \xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}\right)\Bigg|\, \xi\right] 
$$
In the above we just got rid of the expected value over $\delta$, since we now assume that each $\delta_i$ is given.
Step 4:
Goal: introduce missing terms and use the fact that $\mathbb{E}\xi_k = \mathbb{E}\xi'_k=0$, pull out the expectation using Jensen's inequality.
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}^*&\leq \mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j\in\sigma_0}\sum_{k\not\in\sigma_0} \xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}\right)\Bigg|\, \xi\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j\in\sigma_0}\left(\sum_{k\not\in\sigma_0} \xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}+\sum_{k\in\sigma_0}\underbrace{\xi_j\mathbb{E}[\xi'_k]A_{jk}}_{\text{is }0}\right)\right)\Bigg|\, \xi\right]\right]\\
&\overset{\text{Jensen}}{\leq} \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j\in\sigma_0}\sum_{k=1}^M \xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}\right)\Bigg|\, \xi\right]\right]\;\left(\text{how??}\right)\\
&\overset{\text{Fubini}}{=}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{k=1}^M\left(\sum_{j\in\sigma_0}\xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}+\sum_{j\not\in\sigma_0}\mathbb{E}[\xi_j]\xi'_kA_{jk}\right)\right)\Bigg| \xi'\right]\right]\\
&\overset{\text{Jensen}}{\leq}\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j=1}^M\sum_{k=1}^M\xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j,k=1}^M\xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}\right)\right].
\end{align*}
$$
Hence, we finally derive that:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[F\left(\sum_{j\neq
 k=1}^M\xi_j\xi_kA_{jk}\right)\right] \leq
 \mathbb{E}\left[F\left(4\sum_{j,k=1}^M\xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}\right)\right]
$$
And this completes the proof.

Now, I understand pretty much all the logic that goes before Step 4, but then in Step 4, I do not get how do we use the Jensen's inequality to transfer from line $2$ to line $3$.
To my understanding, so that to use the Jensen's inequality, we have to have that the expectation is taken over the entire argument of the convex function, and not just some part of it. In the proof, we have that the new non-contributing term is:
$$
\sum_{k\in\sigma_0}\xi_j\mathbb{E}[\xi'_k]A_{jk}
$$
which is zero because the expectation for any $\xi_i$ is $0$ by construction. Then, assumig that we have to use the Jensen's inequality, we have to have something like this:
$$
\sum_{k\not\in\sigma_0}\xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}+\sum_{k\in\sigma_0}\xi_j\mathbb{E}[\xi'_k]A_{jk}=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k\not\in\sigma_0}\xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}+\sum_{k\in\sigma_0}\xi_j\xi'_kA_{jk}\right]
$$
and I do not understand how this is valid in our case.
Maybe I am not getting some logic, but this is effectively what concerns me, since these several last lines of the proof just do not make sense for me.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
